How to update the state of the modelviewer widget src in model_viewer_plus package in flutter after changing the texture of 3d model using img src
I recently working on a tiles 3d model viewer project where I need to use the static plain tile 3d model src(.glb) and have to dynamically change the texture using image source such as .png, .jpg, etc., using javascript code it works perfectly fine the texture of the 3d model is changing but when I enter to the AR(Argument Reality) mode the texture change doesn't replicate in there. But the same feature is working in perfectly in react web application. Please let me know if there is any possible way to achieve this.
Flutter code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:model_viewer_plus/model_viewer_plus.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class ThreedmodelPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ThreedmodelPage({super.key});

  @override
  _ThreedmodelPageState createState() => _ThreedmodelPageState();
}

class _ThreedmodelPageState extends State<ThreedmodelPage> {
  WebViewController? _controller;
  bool isBorder = false;
  int tileIndex = 0;
  final imgsrcList = [
    "assets/images/tile1_thumbnail.png",
    "assets/images/tile2_thumbnail.png",
    "assets/images/tile3_thumbnail.png",
  ];
  final tileSkin = [
    "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1145811502/photo/digital-ceramic-wall-tile-for-floor.jpg?b=1&s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=2YwQFrQWij1HgiqQWxY5KnZsSbWg6rJerHfedjX49uU=",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/131661/pexels-photo-131661.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/247666/pexels-photo-247666.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600",
  ];
  final imgsrc =
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/131661/pexels-photo-131661.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
  }

  String changeTexture(String imgSrc) {
    return """
   
  async function changeModelColor(imgsrc){
  const modelViewerTexture = document.querySelector("#arMob");
 
      if (!modelViewerTexture) {
      console.error("Model viewer element not found");
      return;
    }

  const material = modelViewerTexture.model.materials[0];

  if (!material) {
      console.error("Material not found");
      return;
    }

  const srcimg = imgsrc;
    if (srcimg) {
     const texture = await modelViewerTexture.createTexture(srcimg);
    material['pbrMetallicRoughness']['baseColorTexture'].setTexture(null);
     material['pbrMetallicRoughness']['baseColorTexture'].setTexture(texture);
    
    } else {
     console.log('image src not found');
      }
   }
   document.querySelector('#arMob').addEventListener('ar-status', (event) => {
        alert(event.detail.status);
    });
    changeModelColor(`$imgSrc`);
    modelViewer.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const initialSrc = controlButtons[0].getAttribute('data-src');
    changeModelColor(`$imgSrc`);
  });

  """;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          children: [
            ModelViewer(
              innerModelViewerHtml:
                  ''' <button id="ar_button" slot="ar-button" style="background-color: white; border-radius: 4px; border: none; position: absolute; top: 16px; right: 16px; ">
       Activate AR
  </button>''',
              key: const ValueKey("assets/models/tiles.glb"),
              id: "arMob",
              autoRotate: true,
              src: "assets/models/plain_tile.glb",
              relatedJs:
                  """const modelViewer = document.querySelector("#arMob");
                     const token = "Token"; """,
              ar: true,
              debugLogging: false,
              arPlacement: ArPlacement.floor,
              cameraControls: true,
              exposure: 1,
              touchAction: TouchAction.panY,
              alt: "Tiles 3d model",
              onWebViewCreated: (value) async {
                _controller = value;
                await _controller!
                    .runJavaScript(changeTexture(imgsrcList[tileIndex]));
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 70,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 150,
                width: 100,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: imgsrcList.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: tileIndex == index
                                  ? Border.all(
                                      color:
                                          const Color.fromRGBO(56, 61, 92, 1),
                                      width: 3)
                                  : null,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                              setState(() {
                                tileIndex = index;
                              });
                              if (_controller != null) {
                                await _controller!.runJavaScript(
                                    changeTexture(tileSkin[index]));
                              }
                            },
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              foregroundImage:
                                  Image.network(tileSkin[index]).image,
                              // child: Image.asset("assets/images/tile1_thumbnail.png"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
[Flutter app output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a7ZcoPJ0FqzYY6ZBsuOmSxjiUGXMbQES/view?usp=drivesdk)

React code working fine:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import '@google/model-viewer';

function Banner2() {
    const modelViewerRef = useRef(null);
    const selectMode = useRef(null);
     const [value, setValue] = useState('3dTiles.png');

    useEffect(() => {
        const modelViewer = modelViewerRef.current;

        const handleLoad = (() => {
            const material = modelViewer.model.materials[0];


            const createAndApplyTexture = async (channel, event) => {
                if (event) {
                    const texture = await modelViewer.createTexture(event);
                    material[channel]['baseColorTexture'].setTexture(null);
                    material[channel]['baseColorTexture'].setTexture(texture);

                }
            }
            console.log(value)

            
            createAndApplyTexture('pbrMetallicRoughness', value);
            
        });

        modelViewer.addEventListener('load', handleLoad);
        // selectMode.current.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            // handleLoad(value);
        // })
    console.log('render')
        // Trigger handleLoad if model is already loaded
        if (modelViewer.model && modelViewer.model.materials.length > 0) {
            handleLoad();
        }

        return () => {
            modelViewer.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad);
        };
    }, [value]);

    return (

        <>
            <model-viewer style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%',position:"relative" }} ref={modelViewerRef} id="blendViewer" ar-placement="floor wall" camera-controls touch-action="pan-y" ar src={'plain1Tile.glb'} alt="A 3D model of an astronaut"
                exposure="1"
            >
                <div  class="controls absolute bottom-5 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2">
                    <div className='flex gap-2'>
                        <div onClick={() => setValue('3dTiles1.jpg')} className="h-10 w-10 p-2 bg-white border border-gray-200 shadow-xl rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-100" >
                            <img src="3dTiles1.jpg" alt="tiles" className="h-5 w-5 object-cover" />
                        </div>
                        <div onClick={() => setValue('3dTiles2.jpg')} className="h-10 w-10 p-2 bg-white border border-gray-200 shadow-xl rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-100" >
                            <img src="3dTiles2.jpg" alt="tiles" className="h-5 w-5 object-cover" />
                        </div>
                        <div onClick={() => setValue('3dTiles.png')} className="h-10 w-10 p-2 bg-white border border-gray-200 shadow-xl rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-100" >
                            <img src="3dTiles.png" alt="tiles" className="h-5 w-5 object-cover" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress-bar" slot="progress-bar">
                    <div class="update-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </model-viewer>

        </>

    );
}

export default Banner2;


React app output
